# my ng-style with filter is not working

Tags: angularjs

This is not working, I dunno if it's a syntax issue somewhere.

I am always getting the color bisque even when the filter is returning a positive number.

```
  <td class="calculatedCol" ng-style= "({{termsList|totalDeviationByKey:'oldspnd':'spend':'optspnd'}})> 0 ? {'color': 'black'} : {'color': 'bisque'}" >
{{termsList|totalDeviationByKey:'oldspnd':'spend':'optspnd' |number:2 }}%</td>
```

The filter in js file is:

```
app.filter('totalDeviationByKey', function () {
    return function (data, key1, key2,key3) {
        if (typeof (data) === 'undefined' || typeof (key1) === 'undefined' || typeof (key2) === 'undefined') {
            return 0;
        }

        var sum1 = 0;
        var sum2 = 0;
        var sum3 = 0;

        for (var i = data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            sum1 += parseInt(data[i][key1]);
            sum2 += parseInt(data[i][key2]);
            sum3 += parseInt(data[i][key3]);

        }
        var A = sum1/sum2;
        var B = sum3/sum2;

        return ((A-B)/A)*100;


    }
});
```

Comment: what `{{termsList|totalDeviationByKey:'oldspnd':'spend':'optspnd' |number:2 }}` prints ?

Comment: @Sachila Ranawaka check the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the double curly brackets, use single curly brackets and change the ternary operation as follow.

```
 ng-style = "{'color': ((termsList|totalDeviationByKey:'oldspnd':'spend':'optspnd')> 0)? 'black' : 'bisque'}"
```

Comment: this worked, thanks, ng-style requires a strange syntax , so I should always start with "{'css attribute' : ....etc}  ?

Comment: yup. that's the best way